# Angular DomSanitizer: Sanitizing Mask-Image Not Working

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular-dom-sanitizer

When providing a background image for an element, everything works fine:

```
<div [style.background-image]="sanitizedStyleValue"></div>
```

But how can I provide a **mask-image** for an element? This:

```
<div [style.mask-image]="sanitizedStyleValue"></div>
```

is not working. Also

```
<div [ngStyle]="{ 'mask-image': 'url( mymaskimage.svg )' }"></div>
```

does not work. I don't even get a warning in the console.

Is this due to DomSanitizer's ignorance of mask images' right for existance, or is there another way to achieve this?

### Context

I want to create an **IconComponent** where I can `Input()` an icon name which will be used as part of an url for the mask image. Another `Input()` holds the background color. This way, I can combine different icons with different colors.

I would like to prevent creating CSS-classes for every possible icon.

Comment: try the answer below, if doesn't work provide stackblitz.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to tell us what the warning in the console is? A Cors warning maybe?

Comment: There is no warning at all in the console

Comment: Sorry, I misread your post about warnings. Try `<div [style.-webkit-mask-image]="sanitizedStyleValue"></div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image#Browser_compatibility), for CSS masks to work with chrome, you need to prefix the rules with `-webkit-`

So this shoud work

```
<div [style.-webkit-mask-image]="sanitizedStyleValue"></div>
```

**Note**: According to [W3C recommendations](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-masking-1/#security), the images you are using for the mask must be returned with correct CORS headers.

> User agents must use the potentially CORS-enabled fetch method defined by the [HTML5] specification for all ,  and  values on the mask-image, mask-border-source and clip-path properties. When fetching, user agents must use “Anonymous” mode, set the referrer source to the stylesheet’s URL and set the origin to the URL of the containing document. If this results in network errors, the effect is as if the value none had been specified.

Comment: I can confirm this is working! Tried pretty much everything before that, thanks @David.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :-**

```
[ngStyle]="{ 'mask-image': 'url(' + maskedImagedUrl + ')'}"
```

Comment: This is the CSS-only approach which would clearly work. But I want to dynamically set the mask image as a custom Input() of an IconComponent. Updated question. But thanky anyway.

Comment: what is in sanitizedStyleValue ?